# Java While Loop Not Executing

Tags: java, random, while-loop, char

I am attempting to build a simple program, and the first part of my program will not work correctly.

Could someone please check my code and tell me why the while loop will not execute and generate a proper random number?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `!` means `not`.  `!(randNumLower >= 97)` is the same as (andNumLower < 97)`  Similar with the second condition.  You are looking for number that is `ess than 97 **and** more than 122`.

Comment: Post your complete code

Comment: I intentionally used ! so that the while loop would see that randNumLower was 0 and while randNumLower is not within my two valid conditions, it will keep generating a new number until the random number meets my conditions.

Comment: I would except that choice is somehow not getting the desired value. You'd have to post more code involving that to solve the issue.

Comment: I posted the entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean this:

```
while ((num < 97) || (num > 122)) {
    num = randNumList.nextInt(122)+1;
}
```

Three outputs with length 5:

```
ordfg
idlxw
ugznu
```

Your condition should be `||` (or) not `&&` (and). `randNumLower` cannot be both below 97 *and* above 122, it must be one or the other (or in-between).

To use your confusing negations, you'd need:

```
(!(num >= 97) || !(num <= 122))
```

This is harder to read, as far as I'm concerned.

Better yet, skip all that, and just use the correct range:

```
num = randNumList.nextInt('z' - 'a') + 'a';
```

Note that the optimization of using an explicit `StringBuilder` isn't strictly necessary since when it matters it will be used under the covers.

Comment: Thank you for the logic explanation! The negation totally put me on the wrong track and I couldn't figure it out!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your code and question, you wanted something like

```
int choice = 1;
int length = 8;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

Random rand = new Random();
if(choice == 1) {
    //Lowercase Letters
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // from 'a' to ('z' - 'a')
        int randNumLower = 'a' + rand.nextInt('z'-'a');
        sb.append((char) randNumLower);
    }
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Which outputs a String of random lower case letters here.

Comment: +1, my first unedited answer used numbers, although I fixed it before I saw yours, you did it the correct way first. An explanation regarding the original logic would have been good, though :)

Comment: @DaveNewton I saw the range checking on the random and thought let's just generate a value in the correct range. I knew the original logic was incorrect. :)

Comment: Yep--it's always best to use the tools available instead of duplicating through iteration and logic what can be done in a single shot: good call.